# Trying to Load Data between two dates using ajax and php based on user input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get the data from my database to display when the user selects two dates. The first date will be the "start date" and the second will be the "end date" Based on the specifications I was giving, they need to see the data that is between the dates that the user enters. I currently have it working when the user searches for a specific date of the month and the data displays with no problem. The problem I am having is getting the data to display when they input a start and end date to search by. If anyone can see my error or the lack of code that I need, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

**This Is my HTML file**

```
$( "#datepicker , #datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });

</script>

<html>
<body>
    <div id="Search-Form">
        <div id="search-container">
            <label>
                <span>Search :</span>
                <input type="text" name="search" value="" id="datepicker" class="text-field">
                <span>or Between</span>
                <input type="text" name="search2" value="" id="datepicker2" class="text-field">
            </label>
            <div id="search-submit">
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="sumbit" value="SUBMIT" onclick="loadData()">
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div id="queryTable">
    </div>
    <div id="queryTractors">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This Is My ajax.php file**

```
include "../Database/connection.php";

$tractor_Tbl = "Tractor";
$trailer_Tbl = "Trailer";
$data = array();
$TractorData = array();


        if(isset($_REQUEST['search'])) {

            $se = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_REQUEST['search']);
            $se2 = mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $_REQUEST['search2']);

            $query = "SELECT * FROM Trailer WHERE datewashed BETWEEN  '$se' AND '$se2'";

            $result = $connection->query($query);

            while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 

                array_push($data , $info);

            }else{

                echo $connection->error;
            }
        }


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

echo json_encode ($data);
return;

function mysql_fix_string($connection, $string) {

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $string = stripslashes($string);

return $connection->real_escape_string($string);

}

function mysql_entities_fix_string($connection, $string) {

return htmlentities(mysql_fix_string($connection, $string));

}
?>
```

And this is the load function that I currently have.

```
function loadData() {

// Search val
var search = $("input#datepicker").val();
var search2 = $("input#datepicker2").val();
var url = encodeURI('/BLT/Services/ajax.php?search=' + search+'&search2=' + search2);

    $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {

        var html = '';
        html += "<table border='1' border-color='black' cellpadding='2px'><thead>";
        html += "<tr height='43' align='center'>";
        html += "<th cellpadding='2px'><b>Trailer Number</b></th>";
        html += "<th cellpadding='2px'><b>Location</b></th>";
        html += "<th cellpadding='2px'><b>Washer</b></th>";
        html += "<th cellpadding='2px'><b>Exterior Wash</b></th>";
        html += "<th cellpadding='2px'><b>Date Washed</b></th>";
        html += '</tr><tbody>';

        var count = 0;
        $.each( data, function( index, row ) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += "<td cellpadding='2px'>" + row.Trailer_Num + "</td>";
            html += "<td cellpadding='2px'>" + row.Location + "</td>";
            html += "<td cellpadding='2px'>" + row.washer + "</td>";
            html += "<td cellpadding='2px'>" + row.exWash + "</td>";
            html += "<td cellpadding='2px'>" + row.datewashed + "</td>";
            html += '</tr>';

            count++;
        });

        if (count == 0) {

            html += '<tr><td colspan="5">No results were found from your query.</td></tr>';
        }

        html += '</tbody></table>';
        $("div#queryTable").html(html);
    });
}
```

Comment: I did a alert(); to see what it grabs and this is my output /BLT/Services/ajax.php?search=2014-11-01&search2=2014-11-30 so it is grabbing my search fields

Comment: Sorry for the Long delay, Work interfered with accomplishing this task, But I was facing two problems that are now resolved. 1st problem was I never closed my while loop before my if statement, 2nd problem was that I had a copy of the original file so any changes I made on the copy conflicted with the original since every reference called instances within the original. Thank you for the tips and suggestions. PROBLEM FIXED !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function loadData() is sending only the value of datePicker; not the value of 'datePicker2'.
I think that may be the problem. I do not know about the PHP. Can you verify that on PHP side, you are receiving both the dates? If not then i think you should have to rearrange your JSON URL to as follows

```
encodeURI('/BLT/Services/ajax.php?search=' + search+'&search2=' + search2);
```

where search2 is

```
 var search = $("input#datepicker2").val();
```

BTW,  named variables are not quite good. You can name the 'datepicker' and 'datepicker2' as 'startDate' and 'endDate' respectively

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use `BETWEEN`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Trailer WHERE datewashed >= '$se' AND datewashed <= '$se2'";
```

change it

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Trailer WHERE datewashed BETWEEN  '$se' AND '$se2'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us exactly what you are getting in the response? Can you debug as follows?

1. On PHP, are you receiving both the dates?
2. Is my_sql query returns proper result set between the dates
3. On JSP, what is response you got?